# How to implement filter in strict mode in ng-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-grid

I'm Using ng-grid to populate the Data. I'm using the ng-grid internal filter. But its not what i want.

Data is

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                   {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                   {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                   {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                   {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
```

If I search   **"Moroni"** I'm getting the output i needed. But If i search **"roni"**    ( Moroni ) I should not see Moroni name. My question is how can i apply the strict comparison of the key value.

I want the filter should be true only when

`filterText == 'Moroni'` [ exactly matching the text instead substring ]

Answer (score 0):

In the angular docs for filter: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

You find this under `comparator`:

```
true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(expected, actual)}. 
this is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.
```

So try `filter:filterText:true`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its perfectly working in Angular Filter. How would i achieve this in **ng-grid** Filtering

Comment: Sorry about that. According to the ng-grid docs, there doesn't look like there is similar support to angular filtering. You might want to look at `useExternalFilter`.